# Is there an "After reading a bar code event"?

Tags: java, events, barcode-scanner

I am creating a program in Java to register products entered with a bar code scanner. I already know that the bar code scanner works like a keyboard.

How do I tell my program when the scanner ends the read? Is there something like `EndScannerEvent`, `InpurtStringEvent` or something like that?
When I scan something (with the bar code scanner), is the data sent character by character, or in another manner?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Some use a terminator character, some might even use the `10` or `13`, you'd need to verify with your documentation.  Another solution might be to use a `Timer` and `DocumentListener`, rest the timer each time the listener is updated and when the timer is finally allowed to run, you could read the value from the field (as an example for Swing)

Comment: You can also program most barcode scanners (usually by scanning some "settings" barcodes"). I know at my workplace we achieved this by having or barcode scanner be programmed to press enter after it scans a code.

What is the brand of your barcode scanner?

Comment: @DustinRyan-Roepsch , thank you. By default the bar code scanner came with the "enter key" at the end of each reading. I got confussed and i was specting something else at the end of each reading. But i added to my JFrame a JTextFiel and then added "KeyEvent.VK_ENTER". Thak you all again.

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

You can program most barcode scanners (usually by scanning some "settings" barcodes"). I know at my workplace we achieved this by having or barcode scanner be programmed to press enter after it scans a code.